# To go over or review? Referred to study

Tags: grammar, expressions

for example,

> **to go over** something that had learned.
>
> I **review** my script for performance at the school.

I mean the field of the study.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking "which fields of study do you review and which fields of study do you go over"?

Comment: To "go over" is idiomatic, colloquial English, quite acceptable in conversation. Though it is synonymous, as you've used it, with "review", I'd avoid it in formal text. It can also have a different meaning, as in, "You need to go over the lines with your pencil to make them darker."

Comment: Sorry. I refer to "review" used in school. I do not mean to "review" of film critic and books, because apparently, in English "review" means 2 things according as used.

Comment: I would say this: I will review something soon, or Let's review what we just discussed.  Or the review will be held at 9:00 am tomorrow.  "To go over" is slang but used everywhere.  "Let's go over that one more time"  "Do we need to go over that again?"  more properly said "Let's review that one more time" or "Do we need to review that again?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *go over* something is a colloquial way of saying that you will review it, as in inspect/read again. As mentioned in comments, there are other meanings when applied to physical activity - that is, the literal meaning.

- I'll go over the chapters from last week before class
- I'll go over the pencil with a pen
- I'll go over the speed limit